# Shell script giving error in gawk command

Tags: linux

**Question:
Assume that you have a file of student’s result with name “mark.text” having information in sequence as Name, Roll No., Subject1, subject2, subject3 and total marks i.e. total 6 columns. Write a gawk script to search the name ‘Shruti’ and show all the information about that student.**

**this is my file from which i want to print shruti's data:**

cat>marks.text

ram 10 20 30 40 50

riya 89 76 99 76 80

shruti 90 98 99 93 96

**the command I used is:**

grep ‘shruti’ | gawk `{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6}` marks.text

**it is giving me error as:**

bash: {print: command not found

gawk: cmd. line:1: marks.text

gawk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this, this works fine for me.**

gawk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' marks.text | grep 'shruti'

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to pipe grep through to gawk when gawk can do the complete job:

```
gawk '$1=="Shruti" { print }'  marks.txt
```

Where the first space delimited field is equal to Shruti, print the line.